# Why driver.findElement is resulting in java.lang.nullpointerexception null in safari 12.2

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, macos-high-sierra, safaridriver

I am trying to run a java-maven selenium test on Mac OS High Sierra with Safari browser 12.2 version. 
The browser gets launched and the url is loaded but the test fails with java.lang.nullpointerexception null at driver.findElement(By.className("Locator")

I have set the java path in my profile using the information from http://www.sajeconsultants.com/how-to-set-java_home-on-mac-os-x/
I have also enabled Allow Remote Automation in the safari browser.
I tried using various versions of selenium-java 3.14.0 / 3.141.59 through maven pom.xml
I have updated the safari browser to 12.2 version
Also tried running the test on Safari Technology Preview browser

```
WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
//Browser is maximized
driver.manage().window().maximize();
//Browser navigates to the url
driver.navigate().to(url);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.className("Locator");
```

The test fails with java.lang.nullpointerexception: null at the step

```
driver.findElement(By.className("Locator");
```

This code works perfectly fine for other browsers on Windows machine.

This is only stack trace I am getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at SafariTest.LoginUser(SafariTest.java:41)
at SafariTest.test(SafariTest.java:150)
```

Comment: Update the question with the error trace logs